# Computer boot up operations up to loading of bootloader

Tags: cpu, bootloader

I am learning about developing your own operating system. I am aware of what happens once the boot loader is loaded, since I anyway write it myself. However, what operations happen between pressing of the power on switch and loading of boot loader are not very clear.

I know that on a high level, this is what happens:

- Power is supplied to the power unit
- It is checked to see if there any problems with the power supply (POST)
- BIOS is loaded
- BIOS performs some checks
- BIOS loads boot loader

So here are my questions:

- I read somewhere about the RESET signal being constantly sent to the processor when not powered on. When power is supplied, this signal is stopped ? Is this true ? If yes, then who supplies this signal and is the check for a proper power supply made before or after the signal is stopped ? If no, then what happens when the power button is pressed ?
- In brief, what are the operations performed in POST ? Some sources mention POST is performed by hardware, and some say by BIOS. Is that correct ?
- What are the checks performed by BIOS ? Do they involve only checking if all devices are configured correctly ?
- I had also read something about checking of/reading from a CMOS chip. What is that operation, and is that done by BIOS ?

P.S.: If this question is not appropriate for this site, please close it and point me to the correct site. And if someone could add other appropriate tags, it would be helpful.

Comment: *"what are the operations performed in POST?"* -- Consult the list of "beep codes" that the various versions of BIOSes can produce.  Those are the (negative) results of specific tests that are conducted during POST.

Comment: your questions heavily lean toward PC like behavior and pc terms, where there are far more non-PC processors (with bootloaders) out there than there are PC processors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does rather depend on the computer : BIOS (by that name) is relatively recent and "BIOS is loaded" is not normally true, "BIOS is already present" in ROM or Flash memory would be closer to the mark on systems that *have* BIOS.

To answer the questions in order:

1) RESET is not "constantly sent when not powered on" other than RESET is often an active low signal (i.e. 0V) and that's the only voltage present without power. Typically RESET is held low once power is applied, and only allowed to become inactive after long enough for power to stabilise.

Newer desktop PCs may have different arrangements because they have a *standby* power supply which can do things like power the keyboard, Ethernet etc to "wake on demand" but that's got nothing to do with a raw power-up.

2) There is not usually a separate test on the power supply; other than "supply volts > minimum required to run PC" - this test allows RESET to become inactive and the CPU to start.

On some systems RESET persists until the person operating the computer clears it by setting a switch. This allows them to load BIOS or another startup program from paper tape, switches, card deck, whatever; not very common nowadays!

3) The CPU starts fetching and executing instructions at a specific address : for ARM Cortex processors, address 0 : for other CPUs, possibly other addresses; the exact address is published in the CPU databook.

If the BIOS or some other hardwired program (digital watch, washing machine controller, etc) isn't already there, the CPU hangs and nothing happens.

4) The BIOS performs the self test. Checks may include measuring the PSU voltage, tests for how much memory there is, does the memory work, etc; what peripherals there are; is there a hard disk? - it's an open ended list. If the system has a CMOS chip, that probably includes a battery powered clock so the BIOS sets the system time, and may include a list of settings (e.g. which disk the bootloader is on).

Assuming there is a hard disk, with a bootloader on it, and the tests pass, THEN it is normal for the BIOS to load and run the bootloader, and your own OS is up and running...

Comment: ... except for the statement "BIOS (by that name) is relatively recent". Actually, that term has existed since the days of CP/M -- late 1970s. That's more than half the time that electronic computers of any sort have existed. And of course, everyone became familiar with the term with the introduction of the IBM PC in 1980.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Who performs the "supply volts > minimum required to run PC" test ? I'm assuming that would be the same unit that disabled RESET.

Comment: Late 70s is what I meant by "relatively recent" : computers survived 30+ years before BIOS came along. And BIOS then had a rather different role : its main task then was the device driver layer between CP/M and a specific hardware platform. It remained in operation (as it did through most of the DOS era) providing services to the OS, instead of being (mostly) ignored once the bootloader kicked off the OS.

Comment: @Cygnus : yes the supply voltage test and reset logic are often combined : it can be as simple as an op-amp, but there are also "supply voltage supervisor" ICs for the purpose.